# How to unit test components with react hooks?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, react-redux, enzyme

Currently trying to unit test components with hooks (useState and useEffects).
As I have read, lifecycles can only be tested with a mount and not a shallow render.

Implementation code:

```
export function MainPageRouter({issuerDeals, match, dbLoadIssuerDeals}) {
console.log("MainPageRouter")
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);


const selectedIssuerId = match.params.id;
const issuerDeal = filterIssuerDealByIssuerId(issuerDeals, 
selectedIssuerId);

useEffect(() => {
   dbLoadIssuerDeals(selectedIssuerId)
     .then(() => {
        setIsLoading(false);
      })
     .catch(function (error) {
        setIsLoading(false);
        });
  }, [selectedIssuerId]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <MainPageLoading />
  } else if(issuerDeal.length > 0) {
    return <MappedDeal match={match}/>
  } else {
    return <MapDeal match={match}/>
  }

}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    deals: state.deals,
    issuerDeals: state.issuerDeals
  }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  dbLoadIssuerDeals
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MainPageRouter);
```

However doing so results in this error:

```
Warning: An update to MainPageRouter inside a test was not wrapped in 
act(...).

When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into 
act(...):

act(() => {
  /* fire events that update state */
});
```

Test:

```
it('Should render Mapped Deal', () => {
    const dbLoadIssuerDeals = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({
        payload:{ deals: { dealid: "1", sourceCode: "TEST" }, issuerId: "1" } }))
    const props = createProps(issuerDeals, dbLoadIssuerDeals);
    const mainPageRouter = mount(<MemoryRouter><MainPageRouter{...props} /></MemoryRouter>);
});
```

Is there a clean way to test that mainPageRouter would return back MappedDeal or MapDeal? I also understand that using mount is more towards integration tests.

Comment: That is just a warning, not an error. Anyway, did you consider using react testing-library instead of enzyme? https://blog.logrocket.com/enzyme-vs-react-testing-library-a-mindset-shift/

Answer (score 1):

The warning you're getting isn't caused by using hooks *per see* but **because you have a side-effect that causes a state update**.

Something is happening after your component's initial render: you're fetching data from your `dbLoadIssuerDeals` service and updating the local state, resulting in a re-render. However, your test runs right after the first render, meaning it couldn't properly assert anything happening after the effect. You could basically only test that `MainPageLoading` is displayed, but none of the other branching statements. React's `act` testing API is warning you about that.

Running your code in `act` guarantees the execution of state updates and enqueued side-effects. In other words, it lets you "wait" for changes resulting from state updates. You can read more about `act` in [React's official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#act).

I recommend using [React Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro) instead of Enzyme or the test utilities of React DOM directly. It wraps updates and events in `act` for you, allowing you to write more expressive tests without the boilerplate.